Can I use two conditions for one column in a Google spreadsheet using the "query" function and the "where" filtering?
I need to filter the values from the table by two conditions in one column. It doesn't work. I also tried using a filter and searching for new ones didn't help.
=QUERY('Test'!A1:BM;"Select M, N, O, BK, AS where(M='Name' AND M='Names')")

Return an empty table.

Hi Welcome, would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

Kindly try to use OR instead of AND in where(M='Name' AND M='Names').

Because M can't be both Name and Names at the same time...

Try to use OR instead AND
For the formula you provided:
=QUERY('Test'!A1:BM;"Select M, N, O, BK, AS where(M='Name' AND M='Names')")

Try using this approach instead:
=QUERY('Test'!A1:BM,"Select M, N, O where(M='Name' OR M='Names')")

Just make sure to adjust the range to fit your data values as needed.
Sample Output

Reference

OR


I’ve reviewed and updated the reference accordingly, My apologies for any confusion caused.

It works, but I think that "OR" is used to select just one or the other.

Use matches keyword. Try-
=QUERY('Test'!A1:BM;"Select M, N, O, BK, AS where M matches 'Name|Names'")


Or just where M matches 'Names?'

@АлексейЕршов Glad to know! If it helps then please consider accepting (tick mark the answer) the answer to treat the thread as solved.
